# Who is the creator of the secp256k1 standard?

Tags: secp256k1, mastering-bitcoin

There are different accounts as to who created the secp256k1 standard, for example:

**Mastering Bitcoin, p.61**:

> Bitcoin uses a specific elliptic curve and set of mathematical constants, as defined in a standard called secp256k1, established by the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST)

**theymos in [this thread on r/crypto](https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/2fe4lr/secp256k1_vs_nist_curves_which_one_to_use/)**:

> secp256k1 isn't a NIST curve. It was created purely by SECG. SECG also publishes some NIST curves in their standards (such as secp256r1, aka P-256), but secp256k1 isn't one of them.

So who created it?
Is there a 'canonical' publication of it somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be found in https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf:

> SEC 2: Recommended Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters
>
> Certicom Research
>
> Contact: Daniel R. L. Brown (dbrown@certicom.com)
>
> January 27, 2010
>
> Version 2.0
>
> c©2010 Certicom Corp.

In section 2.4.1, "Recommended Parameters secp256k1".

Comment: Is it then correct to state that NIST doesn't have anything to do with the secp256k1 standard?

Comment: Yes, NIST has nothing to do with the secp256k1 standard. Some NIST-invented curves are standardized both through NIST and through SECG (e.g. NIST P-256 is the same curve as SECG secp256**r**1), but secp256k1 is not one of them. It was constructed by Certicom, and only standardized through SECG (SECG is basically Certicom...).

Comment: **UPDATE:** secp256k1 was indeed _created_ by SECG/Certicom back around 2000 (SEC2 v2 is 2010, but v1 was 2000), but as of Feb. 2023 it is _also_ 'allowed' by NIST for blockchain, see [SP800-186](https://csrc.nist.gov/pubs/sp/800/186/final) Appendix H.2 .